# Eclipselink Expression filter OR clause

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'm having problems creating a proper query using an eclipselink expression when it comes to needing an OR clause. This is my code:

```
Expression filter = /* filter is not null */;

if (secondStatus != null) {
    Integer second = ticketService.getStatusIdByName(secondStatus);

    filter = filter.and(
                 builder.get(Complaint.propertyName.status)
                     .equal(second)
                     .or(builder.get(Complaint.propertyName.status)
                     .equal(status)));

    // Also tried the below
    // filter = filter.or(builder.get(Complaint.propertyName.status).equal(second));
}
```

The first way only returned a query including one of the statuses, meanwhile the second (commented out) way returned it's own subquery. Both ways I was getting incorrect results. What is the correct way to incorporate an OR clause into a query?

Comment: you may want to add a query interceptor, I've found them helpful for re-writing the SQL

Comment: More information needed- what SQL are you getting, and what results?  Your first example is using JPQL equivalent to  "something AND ( status=:second OR status=:status)", while the second is "something OR (status = :second)".  What exactly are you after?

Comment: @Chris I want to pull up all objects with a status of new or pending for example. What I've been getting is the objects of status new (with all previous filtering ex. a date range) and then additionally all objects of status pending without any of the previous filtering.

Comment: I need to produce something along the lines of SELECT * FROM TABLEX WHERE NAME = "TEST" AND STATUS = NEW OR STATUS = PENDING

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was missing the initial filter in the second statement assuming it would produce the proper SQL automatically.

```
filter = filter.and(builder.get(Complaint.propertyName.status)
.equal(second)
.or(filter.and(builder.get(Complaint.propertyName.status)
.equal(status))));
```

This works as intended.

Comment: How?  You have filter.and in there twice.  Presumably this is giving you "something AND ( status =:second OR ( something AND status = :status))".  This is pretty much the same thing as your original statement. if it works, great, but your original should have too, so I'm guessing something else changed as well.  Maybe what you put in the question wasn't exactly what you were trying.

Comment: In your estimation what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your comment shows the SQL that you want.  This does not generate that SQL.  If it works, great, but your first attempt that you were showing in your question seems much closer to that than this.  You should check the generated SQL to see what might have been going wrong.